# Update RDDs in a loop

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using dataframes/pyspark for my processing. My data frame contains several columns and a primary key column, say TXN_ID. This is my pseudo code -

1. Read TXN_IDs from already processed data in a data frame and call cache() since we will be using it in further processing. Let's call this data frame as **observer_txn_ids**
2. Build a data frame from new incoming raw data file and filter TXN_IDs already processed in the past (we have these ids from step 1, observer_txn_ids)
3. Save the data frame and update observer_txn_ids with the new ids observed in current processing file
4. Process next file(s) i.e repeat steps 2 and 3

In this workflow, I am updating observer_txn_ids data frame in a loop, which creates a new RDD/dataframe each time that it is updated so cache() is not much helpful. How can I optimize this code? or what is an efficient approach to this problem?

P.S observer_txn_ids can grow to have several million values.

Comment: Apache Spark isn't suitable for this case as described in your question.

Comment: @eliasah Thanks for your comment. Do you think that instead of keeping observer_txn_ids as an RDD and using left_anti join for filtering, it makes sense to convert it to a python list of ids and rewrite code to use map() for filtering ids which were already processed. In that case, I wonder if I should use it as a list and let spark ship it to every executor within the closure or define a global variable, and broadcast it everytime in the loop when it gets updated?

Comment: I can't say. But I can add the following: Spark isn't suitable for performing small update on its data. It's not a DB. Also, if your data fits in memory don't use Spark.